# How to use the new repo.magento.com

Tags: magento2, magento-connect

I've generated a new Magento Connect key per [the developer documentation instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html).  How am I supposed to use this key?  i.e., if I try getting info, I see the following.

```
$ composer info magento/sample-data
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username:
```

If I try following the new installation instructions, I get the same thing.

```
$ composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username:
```

Is the key my password?  If so, what's the username?  If the key's a true key (i.e. no usename/password needed) where do I configure the key?

Comment: @Flyingmana  The author did read through the documentation, and the documentation made no mention that a Magento key pair corresponds to composer username/password.  Perhaps that's obvious to some, but it's not obvious to all.

Comment: The documentation changed shortly after the GA. Out of the gate it required the account username/password (which I'm not sure work anymore), but then they updated it. Yeah…huge oversight, but at least it's using generated tokens now. :)

Comment: I'll leave it to OP to close the question. Docs were updated after the fact.

Comment: @Flyingmana seriously if we are going to close every question because somebody did not read the documentation.. then what is a purpose of stackexchange

Comment: I noticed at day 1 of magento2 released but not asked due to this reason that i was not sure about the key. @AlanStorm you are correct thank you for make it more clear.

Comment: What's the deal anyway with this login? Do they want to collect user accounts? I don't get it.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Magento comes with a sample file in your root as `auth.json.sample` you need to copy it to `auth.json`

It contains 2 key sets: 1 for Github and 1 for the Magento Repo

[image]

Enter the following data to your `auth.json` file to login. Please use the Public Key and the Private Key

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username":"<your public key>",
            "password":"<your private key>"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

nb. the auth file can also be found in your user root directory and hence be used elsewhere  ~/.composer/auth.json

Comment: Or enter your public key as the username and private key as the password at the prompts.

Comment: the file is in ~/.composer/auth.json and in magento root

Comment: You must generate keys from Magento Marketplace see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Comment: why is username called public key or vice versa?  The prompt should ask for public key etc!  Why create the confusion with different labels?

Comment: Whenever I try to generate a new key on the site and enter in a name, the modal goes away and nothing happens.

Comment: Where i need to save auth.json file?

Comment: The  position of `auth.json` except `~/.composer/` and `magento_root_folder/`, sometime it is in `~/.config/composer/`(in Ubuntu 18.04). Edit the file, you could update the user of repo.

Comment: Once you have a Magento account and are signed in. Here is the current link for your access keys: https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/

Comment: Note that the composer' configuration path has changed. Check `[home]` variable with command `composer config --list`

Answer (score 36):

Previous example is correct. In addition... it's also possible by composer's config command.

`composer.phar global config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>`

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably add that to the documentation, which is recently updated: http://bit.ly/1SMMh9p

Comment: I think composer.phar may be deprecated. `composer config --global http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>` will work.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 16):

Login in [magento](https://magento.com/) using your credentials.
Then follow the navigation

1.My Account

2.Marketplace

3.My Access Key

4.Magento2

Public Key: xxxxx

Private Key:xxxxx

Public Key used as user name and Private Key used as password.

Answer (score 14):

Previous examples are correct. In addition it is also possible by composer's config command.

Inside the Magento project directory execute the following [*Composer*](https://getcomposer.org) command:

```
$ composer config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>
```

Just replace the placeholders with the actual values (*public_key* will become the *username* and *private_key* the *password* in HTTP authentication with *repo.magento.com*).

The auth settings can be tested by using fetching latest version with a faked update:

```
$ composer update --dry-run
```

This will give an error message like:

> ```
> Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.
> ```

if something is wrong with the credentials.

I can strongly suggest to manage credentials inside the project folder as my answer suggests. I also would not edit the `auth.json` by hand but just with the composer command as it is less error-prone.

Comment: Where i can i add this : composer.phar config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>

Comment: @Rathinam You don't add it, you execute it. the command is "composer", see composer documentation on how to use that utility for all the details: https://getcomposer.org

Answer (score 4):

To Find Authentication username & password . Just follow below steps

```
Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
      Username:
```

1. open https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/account/ & Login
2. Click on 'My Profile'
3. click 'Marketplace' Then Click 'My Access' link
4. On My Access Keys page, click on 'Magento 2' tab
5. click on 'Create A New Access Key' button, you will get two keys Public and Private: Public Key is your username; Private Key is your password
6. Copy key

Comment: yes, its clear instruction

Answer (score 3):

All answers are good just to compile possible scenarios on a single place.

Magento announced a new way to communicate to marketplace via compsoer, when you run `composer install` in the root directory of Magento it will prompt for username and password, remember this is not the Magento username and password it is Public and Private key of Magento Marketplace.

> Login to Magento Marketplace.
>
> Go to My Account.
>
> Under My Products click Access Keys.
>
> Select ver of Magento (1 or 2).
>
> Click Create A New Access Key, in popup box name your key.
>
> Clicking on Ok will generate pair of keys, Public and Private.

Now in Magento root or open `~/.composer/auth.json` and put following lines

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username":"<your public key>",
            "password":"<your private key>"
        }
    }
}
```

You are good to go. Remember `auth.json` file contains standard json if you see any error just make sure that your auth file contains valid json, you can validate your json on [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

If you don't want to add this information in above mentioned file (although it is handy, you don't need to open Marketplace dashboard repeatedly), then on run time just enter your **Public key as username** and **Private key as your password**, if you didn't add pair of keys in `auth.json` in previous step, don't worry Magento will ask you here whether to store this information or not, the choice is yours! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying from the command line interface :

```
Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
```

```
Username: "Your public key"
```

```
Password: "Your private key"
```

Remember here Username means "public key" and password means "private key"
Keep developing...

Answer (score 1):

If this code will give error like `auth.json does not contain valid JSON Parse error on line 1:`

```
"http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
       "username":"<your public key>",
       "password":"<your private key>"
    }
}
```

Than it will be like below:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
       "repo.magento.com": {
          "username":"<your public key>",
          "password":"<your private key>"
        }
    }
}
```

**Here You should Wrap your `auth.json` File with extra `{}`**