# Magento2 composer module:uninstall: Does it make sense and why does it take so long?

Tags: magento2, composer, uninstall

We want to streamline a magento installation managed via composer.

So, for example we have no need for Magento_SendFriend module, nor Magento_Review, and maybe other not essential / small modules.

So [following the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html) I would issue the following command:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r -c Magento_SendFriend
```

So far so good, as it starts to rattle through ..

```
You are about to remove code and/or database tables. Are you sure?[y/N]y
Enabling maintenance mode
You are removing data without a database backup.
No data to clear in Magento_SendFriend
Removing Magento_SendFriend from module registry in database
Removing Magento_SendFriend from module list in deployment configuration
Removing code from Magento codebase:
```

However, it has been stuck there for the past hour and a half, with the only edits I have found having been done to the `app/etc/config.php`.

```
-    'Magento_SendFriend' => 1,
```

Does it make sense to use this new option to remove unused or unneeded modules?

Is it normal for it to take this long?

Comment: I cannot comment about how long it's taking; have you looked in Magento, web server, PHP logs? As to the command, at the very least it's valuable because it checks for dependencies. Unless it's your own module you might not realize there are dependencies with other modules.

You could try using the [dependency checker](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-depen.html#config-cli-depend-rpt-run) and trying it manually but you should back everything up first.

Comment: @tecjam how did you initially deploy Magento? via composer create project? via git or via zip downloaded from magento.com?

Comment: @Maddy I installed it via composer. And this is still happening, even with non-magento-core modules. For example, firegento-magesetup2 -> the last update to version 2.0.1 breaks the store due to missing the necessary `UpgradeSchema` file. Uninstalling and re-installing fixes this, but it is forever stuck uninstalling ... Link: https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup2

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to run : composer update in an other console

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63899)

Comment: I had the same problem and i solved it by this command `composer update ` in another console, i don't wanna reputations, i just wanna help people

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Composer stoped in load data from repo.magento.com

My auth.json was not correct. This decision helped me

```
config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>
```

[How to use the new repo.magento.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90983/how-to-use-the-new-repo-magento-com)