# Magento 2 : Upgrade from 2.0.0 to latest version

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I want to upgrade my magento 2.0.2 to latest version with help of composer.
When i run command

> composer update

It want below authentication information :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
    Authentication required (connect20.aveo-trade.cz):
      Username:
```

But i don't have any username and password for connect20.aveo-trade.cz

Now what i have to do for upgrade?

Comment: How to use the new repo.magento.com http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90983/how-to-use-the-new-repo-magento-com

Comment: actually i know this ,first it ask for repo.magento credentials and i enter that and after that it ask for above credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i solved my issue by removing below code under 'repositories' section from composer.json file :

```
"atconnect": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://connect20.aveo-trade.cz"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open this [link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customerdata/accessKeys/list/), If you don't have account on Magento marketplace then simply create it.After login into your account open the `Access Keys` link from My profile.

[image]

After that click on `Create new access keys` button to generate key for you. After entering key name  It will generate `public key` and `private key` for you. `Public key` is `user name` for you and `private key` is `password` for you. Now you can enter your `user name` and `password` in your command prompt.

[image]

Comment: i have account and when i run update command first it ask for repo.magento credentials and i enter that and credentials are proper after that it ask for connect20.aveo-trade.cz authentication