# Unable to place order

Tags: checkout, orders, payment-gateway, magento2.1.5

I have installed the **Inchoo_Stripe** extension which I found in [https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe](http://here) and follewed this tutorial: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/ .

I have created a test account in stripe. Got an API key.
After lots of search on internet managed to get it on frontend. I used a test credit card info as:

```
card no: 42424242424242  
cvc: 123   
expiry date: some future year and month.
```

as I click place order I get error as follow:
[image]

Comment: try to change the error message to $e->getMessage() in vendor/magento/module-checkout/model/GuestPaymentInformation.php

Answer (score 1):

As the extension creator shared that this extension is **for educational purposes only, do not use in production!**

If you still are using this extension, Make sure that you have installed all dependencies via composer:-

```
composer config repositories.inchoostripe git https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe.git

composer require inchoo/stripe:dev-master
```

Comment: I tried to follow you. I got following warning when I entered the second command:Cannot create cache directory /home/purushotam/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.magento.com/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/purushotam/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/purushotam/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

Comment: The reason is that your var/cache is not writeable. You will need to make it writeable

Comment: I made it writable. But same happens. I forgot to give you full warning. At last it asks for user name as : Loading composer repositories with package information
    Authentication required (repo.magento.com):       
      Username:

Comment: You will need to create your account and enter the required details. Username will be Username, and password will be key.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90983/how-to-use-the-new-repo-magento-com this link can help you for the composer thing

Comment: I created account in magento marketplace. Created access keys. I used public key as username and private as password. I changed the ownership of .composer/.. so that it could be written. I came close to success but not at end:    Do you want to store credentials for repo.magento.com in /home/purushotam/.composer/auth.json ? [Yn] y
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)            
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
  [Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]

Comment: rest of the warning I could not write in above comment is :   The contents of http://packagist.org/p/provider2013%24282624b7b1179ec0d51dee126b20ab296da607a795c71f7b3a88aa60ec832857.json do not match its signature. This should indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer ag  ain and report this if you think it is a mistake.

Comment: Check this for the fix:-
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5196

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69044/discussion-between-anime-and-jd-wtw).