# Mage 2.3 Error Entering Access Keys

Tags: ssl, magento2.3.0

Working on a client installation and trying to enter the access keys so I can connect to Magento Marketplace, I receive the following error upon saving the config:

Failed to connect to repo.magento.com port 443: Connection timed out

I confirmed that TLS is current - set to 1.2 on the Magento server (this was mentioned as a potential issue in another forum).

The current installation does NOT have an SSL certificate - could this be the problem?

If not, any other ideas?

**** EDIT ****

I found some articles talking about open SSL potentially being the issue. I hope some of this information helps to pinpoint the issue

I updated by open SSL, version is now:
[root@s50-63-160-164 public_html]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019

Verified that the same version is being used by PHP by running phpinfo() script:
OpenSSL 1.0.2r 26 Feb 2019

Ran some additional tests per the following article:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5239

---

$context = stream_context_create();
$contents = file_get_contents('https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', false, $context); // this fails

---

$context = stream_context_create();
$contents = file_get_contents('https://packagist.org/packages.json', false, $context); // this succeeds

---

[root@s50-63-160-164 public_html]# openssl s_client -connect repo.magento.com:443 -tls1_2

connect: Connection timed out

connect:errno=110

---

[root@s50-63-160-164 public_html]# openssl s_client -connect repo.magento.com:443 -tls1_1

connect: Connection timed out

connect:errno=110

---

Comment: Hi are you using the CLI?

Comment: Hi are you using the CLI?

Comment: @DavaGordon nope http://www.beastron.com/php_sapi_name.php

Answer (score 0):

Try

`composer config -g -- disable-tls true`

Also what about doing it I  configuration?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90984/70343

Comment: executed the composer command - all that changed is that it errored out much faster. The config is set up correctly (per the link you provided)